# User profile is available. Using '/Users/thomas/.aspnet/DataProtection-Keys' as key repository; keys will not be encrypted at rest

Tags: .net

I don't know why or how this came about?
User profile is available. Using '/Users/thomas/.aspnet/DataProtection-Keys' as key repository; keys will not be encrypted at rest.
I did not use IDataProtectionProvider.
please help
please